# Nginx "Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code."

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, arch-linux, nginx, manjaro

systemctl status nginx.service:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-03-25 21:16:34 +03; 49s ago
  Process: 6071 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 25 21:16:31 lvlzyro nginx[6071]: 2019/03/25 21:16:31 [warn] 6071#6071: could not build optimal types_hash, you should increase ei>
Mar 25 21:16:31 lvlzyro nginx[6071]: 2019/03/25 21:16:31 [emerg] 6071#6071: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Mar 25 21:16:32 lvlzyro nginx[6071]: 2019/03/25 21:16:31 [emerg] 6071#6071: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Mar 25 21:16:32 lvlzyro nginx[6071]: 2019/03/25 21:16:31 [emerg] 6071#6071: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Mar 25 21:16:33 lvlzyro nginx[6071]: 2019/03/25 21:16:31 [emerg] 6071#6071: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Mar 25 21:16:33 lvlzyro nginx[6071]: 2019/03/25 21:16:31 [emerg] 6071#6071: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Mar 25 21:16:34 lvlzyro nginx[6071]: 2019/03/25 21:16:31 [emerg] 6071#6071: still could not bind()
Mar 25 21:16:34 lvlzyro systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 25 21:16:34 lvlzyro systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 25 21:16:34 lvlzyro systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

journalctl -xe:

```
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The unit nginx.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 25 21:16:34 lvlzyro systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- A start job for unit nginx.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 2771 and the job result is failed.
Mar 25 21:16:34 lvlzyro audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=nginx comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib>
Mar 25 21:16:34 lvlzyro kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1553537794.290:95): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=nginx c>
Mar 25 21:16:34 lvlzyro sudo[6068]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 25 21:16:47 lvlzyro kernel: psmouse serio1: Touchpad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 6
Mar 25 21:16:47 lvlzyro kernel: psmouse serio1: Touchpad at isa0060/serio1/input0 - driver resynced.
Mar 25 21:19:05 lvlzyro wpa_supplicant[808]: wlp5s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Mar 25 21:19:11 lvlzyro gnome-shell[912]: Ignoring excess values in shadow definition
Mar 25 21:19:11 lvlzyro gnome-shell[912]: Ignoring excess values in shadow definition
Mar 25 21:19:11 lvlzyro gnome-shell[912]: Ignoring excess values in shadow definition
Mar 25 21:19:11 lvlzyro gnome-shell[912]: Ignoring excess values in shadow definition
```

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: `bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)` seems to indicate there is a service already running on port 80.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear it. =)